# Move SELECT to SQL Server side

Tags: sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008, select, sqlclr

I have an SQLCLR trigger. It contains a large and messy SELECT inside, with parts like:

```
(CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT * FROM INSERTED I WHERE I.ID = R.ID)
THEN '1' ELSE '0' END) AS IsUpdated -- Is selected row just added?
```

as well as JOINs etc. I like to have the result as a single table with all included.

**Question 1**. Can I move this SELECT to SQL Server side? If yes, how to do this?

Saying "move", I mean to create a stored procedure or something else that can be executed before reading dataset in while cycle.

The 2 following questions make sense only if answer is "yes".

Why do I want to move SELECT? First off, I don't like mixing SQL with C# code. At second, I suppose that server-side queries run faster, since the server have more chances to cache them.

**Question 2**. Am I right? Is it some sort of optimizing?

Also, the SELECT contains constant strings, but they are localizable. For instance,

```
WHERE R.Status = "Enabled"
```

"Enabled" should be changed for French, German etc. So, I want to write 2 static methods -- OnCreate and OnDestroy -- then mark them as stored procedures. When registering/unregistering my assembly on server side, just call them respectively. In OnCreate format the SELECT string, replacing {0}, {1}... with required values from the assembly resources. Then I can localize resources only, not every script.

**Question 3**. Is it good idea? Is there an existing attribute to mark methods to be executed by SQL Server automatically after (un)registartion an assembly?

Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question 1.
http://www.sqlteam.com/article/stored-procedures-returning-data

Question 3.
It looks like there are no appropriate attributes, at least in [Microsoft.SqlServer.Server Namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.server.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Well, the SQL-CLR trigger will also execute **on the server**, inside the server process - so that's server-side as well, no benefit there.

But I agree - triggers ought to be written in T-SQL whenever possible - no real big benefit in having triggers in C#.... can you show the the whole trigger code?? Unless it contains really odd balls stuff, it should be pretty easy to convert to T-SQL.

I don't see how you could "move" the SELECT to the SQL side and keep the rest of the code in C# - either your trigger is in T-SQL (my preference), or then it is in C#/SQL-CLR - I don't think there's any way to "mix and match".

Comment: Unfortunately, it uses multiple COM servers, so converting in pure T-SQL is not an option.

Comment: @noober: you could use sp_OACreate to instantiate and use COM stuff from within T-SQL...

Comment: I would be careful about using sp_OACreate. We have seen issues with "out of Memory" exceptions from using the sp_OA functions. This was supposedly fixed in SP3 for SQL Server 2005 but it did not fix it for us and we had to remove it. We haven't had any problems since the sp_OA* references were removed.

Answer (score 1):

To start with, you probably do not need to do that type of subquery inside of whatever query you are doing.  The INSERTED table only has rows that have been updated (or inserted but we can assume this is an UPDATE Trigger based on the comment in your code).  So you can either INNER JOIN and you will only match rows in the Table with the alias of "R" or you can LEFT JOIN and you can tell which rows in R have been updated as the ones showing NULL for all columns were not updated.

Question 1) As marc_s said below, the Trigger executes in the context of the database.  But it goes beyond that.  ALL database related code, including SQLCLR executes in the database.  There is no client-side here.  This is the issue that most people have with SQLCLR: it runs inside of the SQL Server context.  And regarding wanting to call a Stored Proc from the Trigger: it can be done BUT the INSERTED and DELETED tables only exist within the context of the Trigger itself.

Question 2) It appears that this question should have started with the words "Also, the SELECT".  There are two things to consider here.  First, when testing for "Status" values (or any Lookup values) since this is not displayed to the user you should be using numeric values.  A "status" of "Enabled" should be something like "1" so that the language is not relevant.  A side benefit is that not only will storing Status values as numbers take up a lot less space, but they also compare much faster.  Second is that any text that is to be displayed to the user that needs to be sensitive to language differences should be in a table so that you can pass in a LanguageId or LocaleId to get the appropriate French, German, etc. strings to display.  You can set the LocaleId of the user or system in general in another table.

Question 3) If by "registration" you mean that the Assembly is either CREATED or DROPPED, then you can trap those events via DDL Triggers.  You can look here for some basics:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175941(v=SQL.90).aspx

But CREATE ASSEMBLY and DROP ASSEMBLY are events that are trappable.

If you are speaking of when Assemblies are loaded and unloaded from memory, then I do not know of a way to trap that.